# Почему я не могу так описать интерфейс?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Почему я не могу указать, что в объекте есть ключи `id`, `_id` со значением типа строки и какие-то еще ключи со значением объекта?

```typescript
interface ITest
{
    _id: string;
    id: string;
    [ keyContent: string ]:
    {
        [ keyText: string ]: string;
    };
}
```

> Свойство "_id" типа "string" не может быть назначено типу индекса "string" "{ [keyText: string]: string; }". ts(2411)

> Свойство "id" типа "string" не может быть назначено типу индекса "string" "{ [keyText: string]: string; }". ts(2411)

Пример данных:

```typescript
const test = [
    {
        "_id": "63a45f54f21c59fef23a637b",
        "id": "63a45f54f21c59fef23a637b",
        "test2":
        {
            "value1": "stackoverflow",
            "value2": "test"
        },
        "test":
        {
            "title": "My next"
        }
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вот этим объявлением

```
    [ keyContent: string ]:
    {
        [ keyText: string ]: string;
    };
```

вы указали, что значения вашего типа, индексируемого строкой, должны иметь тип

```
    {
        [ keyText: string ]: string;
    };
```

каждый. И получается противоречие, когда вы также говорите, что `id` и `_id` должны быть строками.

Если вы имеете в виду, что вам нужен тип, где все значения - это вложенные объекты `строка-строка`, но при этом в корне лежат строковые `id` и `_id`, то можете попробовать сделать например так:

```
type TTest = {id: string, _id: string} & {[P: string]: Record<string, string> | string}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKjEGdhQLxQN4EsAmAuKSATpgHYDmANFAPo75GlkC%20UAZBgNoAK9wx5AXXwAlCAGMA9oWwAeBuSryyAPigAfAn0ZMAUDskkkUYImD44pjgNRQO6HVEdQARLWzP8zgGwBmAIYALACsAGZBASEATACMYkEAnCEQUf6%20AOwARs4UDk7OOB4uvoGh4VGxCUkpfulZOU4uJkiRhfYNDc4Abn4ANgCuENGFzkh%20YgDWEp0QhCE9EgDu2bntLt39EC2eTcDOK1BM9Xk7rfsdwJjAPRDDALIgUCQQAB67ubpMAgDcejscAAwCAB0O0iUAA9OCoIB2EEALCCAVhBAIIggBkQKCAWRBAEIggD4QKCAbhBABwggEYQHFYwmAKRB4YAuEAxVAJxKgiIxgAEQLGUwAMIECoIB8ECxmKxgB4QQDCIFBALwggsAbCAinGAfhAmfjAEwgWNh%20IxqPlTMFgHEQMWAORAqOzKaL8eL4To-oCQaYwX4EFBRJJpHItApNPwVEA).

Comment: Ваш вариант не работает, и хотелось бы, чтобы я мог называть "ключи" (keyText, keyContent). Я добавил в вопрос пример данных.

Comment: @OliverPatterson а зачем вам это?

Comment: Удобство (нужно ещё 7 символов...)

Comment: Ну можете попробовать `Record<string, ...>` заменить на `{[keyTest: string]: ...}`

Comment: Тоже самое. Есть еще варианты?

Comment: Я наверное неправильно вас понял, что вам нужно

Comment: Обновил ответ. Предыдущий действительно был не совсем корректный.

Comment: Тогда я смогу сделать `[{ _id: string; id: string; } & { [ keyContent: string ]: { [ keyText: string ]: string; } | string; }];`, ну пусть уже остается так. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, можете, конечно, если это столь принципиально.